# Can infinite unions in some sense be handled like limits?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm stuck on a question regarding sets that are covered by an infinite union of sets. If a set $S$ is a subset of an infinite union of sets,

$$S\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}{U_k}$$

is it then correct to say that if $x_0\in S$ then $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$x_0\in\bigcup_{k=1}^{N}{U_k}$$

similar to what we would say if a limit exists?

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Comment: This is a good opportunity to check yourself. What is the negation of your proposed relationship? Does the negation make sense? If the negation is false, then the relationship is true.

Comment: I have not been introduced to such a precise definition as the one you showed, that is probably the reason for why I asked this question. I understand it better now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if $x_{0}\in S$ then $x_{0}\in\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}{U_{k}}$ and by definition this implies $x_{0}\in U_{m}$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$, therefore there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ (any $N\geq m$ does the job) such that
$$x_{0}\in\bigcup_{k=1}^{N}{U_{k}}$$